# I get UNDEFINED when I use req.param inside expressjs and nodejs inside my post controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a serious problem :D...I'm trying do some tutorials about node and express and with last one I'm get a error, the tutorial I'm trying to do is it

```
http://www.ianwootten.co.uk/2011/02/07/blog-rolling-with-couchdb-express-and-node-js
```

and the error is it

when I use `req.param('title')` I always get a big `undefined` and it is saved inside my couchdb, I debug this and...I'm pretty sure the error is inside my request param, obviously my view has a input field named title
I've tried `req.body('title')` and `req.param.title` and I get the same "error"

I'm using the latest release for express and node...and I change bodyDecoder for bodyParse..I'm using jade for template my views...

```
app.post('/blog/new', function(req,res){
  articleProvider.save({
    title: req.param('title'),
    body: req.param('body')
  }, function(error, docs) {
    res.redirect('/')
  });
});
```

what can I do??...thanks everybody for read and for the help...

Answer (score 5):

make sure to use the body parser

`app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Then get your title using `req.body.title`

`title` is a property of body. `body` is not a method.

Comment: Hi , Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request . could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined or null?